# How to Last Name field validation for Contacts module in Sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am using the SugarCRM version 6.5.26 and  I need to validate last_name so that it only accept alphabet Character in contact module. This need to be done on edit view. Currently it accept all type of value due to no validation on input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a reference to the javascript file which will be needed for event binding.

**Path:**  *custom/modules/Contacts/metadata/editviewdefs.php*

**Code:**

```
<?php

$viewdefs['Contact']['EditView']['templateMeta']['includes'] =
array (
array (
'file' => 'custom/modules/Contacts/js/editview.js',
),
);
```

?>

2. Add the javascript file you want to include into the location you referenced above(custom/modules/Contacts/js/editview.js). Check last_name field ID and use following code

   > $('input#last_name').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
   >       var node = $(this);
   >       node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); }
   >       );
3. Quick Repair, then browser hard refresh. All Done !

Comment: Hi Star ,How to write js code for validation in editview.js file

Comment: Contact create page not open when i have Quick Repair only display save nd cancel button

Comment: Turn on error reporting and share details, also check phone and Apache error logs

Comment: have you sorted it out?

Comment: no when i click Quick Repair and Rebuild then remove creating contact form and display only save cancel button

Comment: Hi Star Please first try yourself download sugar 6.5.26 version and developed validation functionality after update your answer Download link :- https://sourceforge.net/projects/sugarcrm/files/latest/download

Comment: i did that multiple time. I think you are not creating custom editviewdefs.php properly. To overcome this, copy if from /modules/Contact/Contacts/metadata/editviewdefs.php to custom/modules/Contact/Contacts/metadata/editviewdefs.php and then add "includes" index accordingly.

Comment: Hi star How to download sugar crm current latest version

Comment: Don't know because they have stopped supporting CE and now people use SuiteCRM instead of using Sugar CE

Comment: this seems separate issue so post it as new question instead of asking multiple things in comments.